# Fetch from MySQL with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm building a web application that connects to a database which has got a couple of variables stored that's necessary for the site to function properly.

Right now I'm using php to connect and fetch the information but in the end it would be much easier to use a .html file, so I'm planning on using AJAX to fetch the information instead.

I've got this code:

```
$(function () 
  {
     $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php',                  
  data: {
        paramName: $("#partyIDInput").val()
    },
  method: post,               
      dataType: 'json',        
      success: function(data)         
      {
        var id = data[0];       
        var pID = data[1];      
        var pLOC = data[2];      
        var pNAME = data[3]; 
        var pFORMID = data[5];     
        var pFORMSONG = data[6];      
        var pFORMARTIST = data[7];       
        var pFORMNAME = data[8];    

        $('#partyTitle').append(""+pNAME+"");
      } 
    });
  });
```

Which fetches all the variables via api.php which looks like this:

```
    <?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxx;dbname=xxxxx;charset=utf8', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');

$partyInput = $_POST['paramName'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM playr_partyID_db WHERE partyID = $partyInput");

$stmt->execute(array($_POST['paramName']));

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

But my problem is that I've got a text input on the web page, when a user writes a "partyID" in it and clicks continue I want the script to fetch the information from the row with that ID. Now it's only fetching from the 1st row.

I've never worked with AJAX before so if you've got the time, please explain what's happening too.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here's the input, note that I haven't optimized the page in terms of css yet.

```
<form style="margin-top:150px;" method="post" action="">
              <div class="list-block">
                <ul>
                  <li class="item-content" style="background: #fff;margin-bottom: -26px;">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                      <div class="item-input">
                        <input style="text-align:center;padding:0;" type="text" name="partyID" placeholder="Ange PartyID">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="list-block">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Festa p&aring;!" class="login_bttn" style="  background: none;color: white;border: 1px solid white;border-radius: 500px;width: auto;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top: 40px;"></input>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="list-block-labe"></div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). Your not sending anything to the PHP script.

Comment: where is your  text input ??

Comment: This isn't the complete page, just the parts that has to to with the db. I'll add the input,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to pass that extra parameter, update `data: "",` to

```
data: {
    paramName: $("#idOfField").val()
},
```

Secondly, as Jay Blanchard mentioned, switch to PDO

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM playr_partyID_db WHERE partyID =?");

$stmt->execute(array($_POST['paramName']));

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Ok, I've changed to PDO.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get it to work. I updated the code in the original post to what I've got now.

Comment: Is $rows empty? Is there any error? Can you paste a print_r($rows)?

Comment: It says that it can't find the variable.

Comment: right below $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FERTCH_ASSOC); add a print_r($rows);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77804/discussion-between-9focuspoints-and-alex-tartan).

Answer (score 2):

You have to send something in the AJAX call -

```
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  
      data: "", // needs to contain the data you want to send
      method: post, // you also need a method
```

Once you do that the variables you send will be available in the `$_POST` array of the PHP and you can include those variables in your SQL query. Here is a [basic AJAX guide](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) which should make things clearer for you.

In addition you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).